# Se puede agregar más de un dato en una columna?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite3, table

Estaba leyendo un poco de SQLite y me surgió la duda de si se puede agregar más de un dato en una columna, me explico mejor:

Supongamos que hay dos tablas y en la primera hay una columna que hace referencia a la columna ID de la segunda tabla, se podría dar el caso en el que tenga un dato que haga referencia a por ejemplo 3 filas de la otra tabla? Abajo muestro un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir.

```
Tabla1 (
    ID,
    Name,
    Tabla2_id
)

Tabla2 (
    ID,
    Name
)
```

En este caso se podria hacer que en Tabla2_id tenga por ejemplo 2 o más ID de la tabla2?

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier cosa vuelvo a formular la pregunta.

Comment: Por supuesto que es posible, en realidad puedes poner todas las referencias a otras tablas que quieras, estas referencias se llaman FK (Foreign Keys) o Claves foráneas, la único límite es la lógica que soporte el diseño de tu base de datos.
Una clave foránea es un campo con un registro que permite identificar dicho registro con otro en otra tabla.

Comment: no.. no podes poner en el campo tabla2_id muchos datos... deberias tener una tabla intermedia si tenes una relacion nxm (o muchos a muchos, o 1 a muchos)... estudia sobre normalizacion de bases de datos...

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, quedo clarísimo.

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible, pero no recomendable, en las bases de datos relaciones se crean estos tipos de campos que instancian los id's de otras tablas, esto con el objetivo de a futuro poder ralacionar estas tablas con otras, es decir, si quisieras podrias hacer un select y obtener los datos de ambas tablas con esta relacion, ejemplo:

```
select * from Tabla1 inner join Tabla2 on Tabla1.Tabla2_id = Tabla2.Id;
```

Si te das cuenta aqui utilizamos el campo de la tabla1 llamado "Tabla2_id" para compararlo con los id's de la tabla dos, esto en gran escala se vuelve util y es la funcionalidad principal de las bases de datos relacionales, es decir tener dos id's de referencia a la tabla dos, es completamente innecesario y puede llegar a causar problemas a futuro con tu software, es por eso que te indico que es posible, PERO, NO recomendable, espero haberte ayudado